# Change image src if the width is larger then original image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that defines the width of an image through html like this:

```
                                                                   ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
<img id="teste" class="item" src="../img/fotos/4medium.jpg" style="width: 430px; display: block; margin-top: -7px; margin-left: 0px; max-width: 9999em; height: auto;"/>`
```

But, if the width of the image is less than 430px, the app expands the image possibly warping or pixelating it.

Is there a way to check if the `style="width"` is bigger than the original picture width and, if so, change the src to another image?

I think that it should look something like this:

```
if ($('#teste').width() > $(4medium.jpg).width()) {
$('img').attr('src', '../img/fotos/4larger.jpg');
} else {
$('img').attr('src', '../img/fotos/4medium.jpg');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the width always going to be set to 430px for all images that are in your "application"?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally this is something you would check with a script on the server (since otherwise you potentially will have to download both images to the client).  Something like this should work:

```
var testImg = new Image();
testImg.src = '../img/fotos/4medium.jpg';
testImg.onLoad = check_image_size( testImg );
```

Then test the width to see if you need to load the larger image:

```
function check_image_size( obj ) {
  var url = obj.src;
  if ( obj.width > 430 )
     url = '../img/fotos/4larger.jpg';
  $('#teste').attr( 'src', url );
}
```

This is an ugly approach (and potentially slow because it potentially could load both images), but I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way to do it client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var teste_img = document.getElementById('teste'); 
var teste_width = teste_img.clientWidth;
var medium_img = document.getElementById('medium'); 
var medium_width = teste_img.clientWidth;


if(test_width > medium_width ){
    $('img').attr('src', '../img/fotos/4larger.jpg');
}else{
    $('img').attr('src', '../img/fotos/4medium.jpg');
}
```

Comment: this is not clear for me: `var medium_img = document.getElementById('medium'); ` there isn't an element "medium"
I tested `alert(teste_width)` and returns 1920 and the image width is 350px.

Comment: yeah, it was an example you should change the id to actual existing elements on your dom

Comment: the element is the same in my answer. I want to compare style width with the src image width...

Comment: You are assigining a fixed width, the image will have that width, I thought you wanted to compare against a different image

Comment: No, is the same image. The same code... The app set a width of the image automatic. And sometimes this is bigger than the image original width.
I want to compare the width set in style and the same image (src) original width to change images...